# Install Mesa backport from openSUSE Build Service?

Tags: debian, backports, mesa

I'm running Debian 10 on my PC.  I'm trying to install a Mesa 19.1.6 backport from [this repository](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:stevenpusser:new-hardware-support-buster) on the openSUSE Build Service.

I tried to install it like this:

```
echo  'deb  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/stevenpusser:/new-hardware-support-buster/Debian_10/  /' >  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:stevenpusser:new-hardware-support-buster.list

rm  -rf Release.key && wget -nv  https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:stevenpusser:new-hardware-support-buster/Debian_10/Release.key  -O Release.key && apt-key add - < Release.key && rm  -rf Release.key**
```

It does not give any error, but I don't know how to upgrade the mesa libs. I gave `apt get update` and `apt get upgrade`, but it does not perform the upgrade.

In fact if I do:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

...it returns the old Mesa already in Buster:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.3.6
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt policy libegl-mesa0`?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe offtopic, but if you want install newer Mesa, you can use *Bullseye (testing)* repository.

1. edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and copy lines looks like:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
```

2. paste it and change `buster` to `bullseye`, looks like:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
```

3. temporary coment lines with `buster` repository:

```
#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
```

4. save changes and exit
5. update repositories state with command `apt-get update`

   - you can see, that data is downloaded from `bullseye` repository, not from default `buster` repository
6. install `mesa` packages with dependencies `apt-get upgrade mesa-* *-mesa`

   - **WARNING: This change dependecies on many packages and exist chance to broke your system! This do it on your own risk! Always check your backups and do fresh one!**
7. revert change in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to default state

   - comment lines with `bullseye` repository and uncoment lines with `buster`
   - again update repository data like in step 5

Now you have new Mesa packages from testing repository, but still have many core packages on default stable version.

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.2.6
```

Please, be very carefull, when you attempt to do upgrade your packages and double check dependecies, from which repository you do this updates! In fact, from testing `bullseye` repository download only neccessary packages.

By this workaround I run Radeon RX 5700 XT under Debian 10.